# I wonder why many resource managers (Yarn, Mesos, Kubernetes etc.) do not support setting the disk I/O resource usage of containers

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop-yarn, mesos

In most resource managers, we can set the container's CPU usage and memory usage.
But I'm curious about the technical reasons for not supporting disk I/O resource allocation for containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Using cgroups to limit I/O](https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/) this requires **cgroups v2** and that is quite recent feature for container runtimes.

For Kubernetes support, you should probably follow [initial kep for qos of storage v0.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1907) and [cgroups v2 was added as alpha feature in Kubernetes 1.22](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/2254).

So it looks like there is work in progress on this.